# Passing a multi-dimensional array from PHP to jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

YES, i read other posts but i still can´t figure this out...

I have a multi-dimensional array in php.

```
json_encode($myarray);
```

Gives me something like this...

```
{"1":[0,0.46,0.23],"2":[0,0.71,0.33],"3":[0,0.7,0.54]}
```

Yes, maaaany floaties. I love them ;). How can i parse it with jQuery? I tried

```
var myarray = $.parseJSON(<?php echo json_encode($myarray); ?>);
alert(myarray[0][0].val());
```

but it doesn´t work :/. Maybe i´m just to dumb right now.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Why doesnt this work? Perhaps, in your sample, it is because you dont enclose your result in string tags. You should debug your code, view the source or check out the error log.

Comment: [`parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) is for *strings* that contain a JSON value. JSON itself however is legal JavaScript, no need to wrap it in a string in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var myArray = <?php echo json_encode($myarray); ?>
```

Since JSON is Javascript, there is no real parsing from one data type to another. JSON is a subset of javascript, its just compatible. Especially jQuery doesnt have anything to do with this.

If the data comes from an unknown source (e.g. the user) you'd want to validate it first.

Answer (score 1):

why would you parse it?

```
var json = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>
```

Comment: json_decode accepts the JSON string, and spits out the PHP object. You'd want to use encode, which does it the other way around.

Comment: @TJHeuvel: sure, it was just a type :)

Comment: Thank you, perfect! Now i even understand the concept! :D